# Configure options for deep framework classes

Tags: c#, properties

Whats the best way to allow the user of an API to change trival options? Meaning that the option has a default that doesn't need to be changed, but they might want to change it in the future. The class is public in the API, but without being directly told what class and what option to change, they would have no idea.

Suppose you have some data object generated by essential API object. This data class might look like:

```
public class SomeComplicatedMessageInterpretter
{
    public static bool ShouldReturnVerboseMessage { get; set; } = true

    public bool TryInterpreMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message + (ShouldReturnVerboseMessage ? "More information": string.Empty));
            return true;
        }
        catch(IOException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, you expect the ShouldReturnVerboseMessage value to be true, but it is not essential for the program operation. So, you make it static get/set, and don't require it in parameters and give it a default value. This means it can be changed, but it doesn't have to be.

Well, from an API user perspective, all they see is something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    APIComponent1 component = new APIComponent1();
    component.Run();
}
```

How are they supposed to know that they can change that thing they find annoying by doing this:

```
SomeComplicatedMessageInterpretter.ShouldReturnVerboseMessage = false;
```

Is there a better way? Or is the only solution good documentation and forums that can answer very specific questions like this?

Comment: This is exactly why documentation exists, so the developer doesn't have to know the nuances of the API. Great documentation also has code-examples on how to use the API for given situations. You could do code-documentation, but it isn't clear in your example how `APIComponent1` relates to `SomeComplicatedMessageInterpretter`, so documentation would be where I (and most others) would look first.

Comment: @RonBeyer I suppose that makes sense. I guess I'm treating my API users too nicely. They can read documentation for the problem's they're having, and the documentation will tell them these things. It still feels wrong to knowingly create something with such poor usability/discoverability.

Comment: You can make it less confusing, for example `APIComponent` could have an optional parameter called `ComplicatedInterpreterSettings` that uses those settings for function calls to the interpreter. See [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: Well, lets say they are 3 different API components that need that need that value, and 3 different settings to set... I guess that actually does make sense. Just an optional parameter for each, and a struct to hold the settings. Though I have a coworker who things options/setting classes are bloatware, and hits me with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it